# Name lookup for local class members inside templates

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, name-lookup, local-class

Consider the following code, that simulates a `constexpr` lambda (proposed for C++17, not available in C++14).

```
#include <iostream>

template<int M, class Pred>
constexpr auto fun(Pred pred)
{
    return pred(1) <= M;
}

template<int M>
struct C
{
        template<int N>
        static constexpr auto pred(int x) noexcept
        {
            // simulate a constexpr lambda (not allowed in C++14)
            struct lambda
            {
                    int n_, x_;

                    constexpr auto operator()(int y) const noexcept
                    {
                            return this->n_ * this->x_ + y;
                            //     ^^^^       ^^^^ <---- here
                    }
            };

            return fun<M>(lambda{N, x});
        }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto res = C<7>::template pred<2>(3);
    std::cout << res; // prints 1, since 2 * 3 + 1 <= 7;
}
```

Here, the `lambda` is defined inside a function template member of a class template. Surprisingly, I have to `this->`ambiguate the `lambda` member variables `n_` and `x_`.

**Live examples** ([with `this->`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af285be11b73e912), [without `this->`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741ef53abc1bae3f))

I was under the impression that this is only necessary in dependent base classes, but the `lambda` class is just a local class, not a dependent base class.

**Question**: can someone point me to the relevant Standardese for name lookup of local class members inside templates?

Comment: The code w/o `this` is accepted by clang++3.7 (ToT). See e.g. http://melpon.org/wandbox/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @dyp, it appears to be a bug in Clang 3.5 / 3.6 that [is fixed in Clang 3.7](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jGA1fnRToa5hVChW) tip of trunk. G++ 4.8.1 through tip of trunk compile this correctly as well.